# Automatic login option is missing in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

Automatic login option is missing from System Settings > User Accounts, how can I solve this?

[image]

I either can't set the automatic login by editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

> [SeatDefaults]
>
> autologin-user=x
>
> autologin-user-timeout=0
>
> user-session=ubuntu
>
> greeter-session=unity-greeter

After restart login screen asks for my password.

There is a thread in Ubuntu forums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11889259 .
It's in lubuntu forum, but there are ubuntu users afected too.

I'm runing 12.04 (precise) 64-bit with Kernel Linux 3.2.0-24-generic.

Excuse my bad english, please.

Comment: Are you sure you 'Unlocked' the settings pane? (Top right)

Comment: Are you sure about this? When I go into my System Settings > User Accounts, I see a button called 'Automatic Login' that is set to OFF.

Comment: I'm sure, I unlocked the settings pane. There is not a Automatic login button

Comment: see this image: http://bit.ly/KVhGmz just like grossogrossum said is unlocked (see rounded area) and pane ends in a passwd field I'm runing 12.04 (precise) 32-bit with Kernel Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae under a virtual box machine.

Comment: @grossogrossum: finaly, I have viewed the "Atomatic Login" option  under my user account; starting a session with guest user, going to User Account and click my username. But activating it via gui doesn't allows to login automatically ... :(

Answer (score 8):

The **Automatic Login** option won't appear if you have an *encrypted home folder* - both features contradict each other.

Comment: So what do you suggest Daniel, for those who have an encrypted home folder?
Is there a way around this?

Comment: did you find out a solution?

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and since my hard drive is also encrypted (on Ubuntu 16.04), I opted to remove my home folder encryption. The process is a little bit convoluted, as it involves creating another user and moving your home folder around, but is thoroughly detailed [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it should "be there" for all users -- but you need to remember to click the unlock on the top-right before you can change it:

[image: login lock]

Comment: I'm not allowed to post an image (I'm new user) but my User Account pane ends in Password ******, and it's unlocked.